# Why is my JavaScript BMI Calculator not working? Cannot find the error

Tags: javascript, html

I have been for a few days now trying to program a basic BMI calculator, but something seems to be wrong. Tried the console, read a thousand posts here but cannot find my error. It just doesn't show any result. I would really appreciate your help.

This is my HTML:

```js
function printImc() {
  var peso = parseFloat(document.getElementById("peso").value);
  var altura = parseFloat(document.getElementById("altura").value);
  var imc = peso / (altura * altura).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("h2").innerHTML = imc;
  var indice = "";
  if (imc <= 18.5) {
    indice = "Tienes bajo peso";
  } else if (imc > 18.6 && imc <= 24.9) {
    indice = "Tienes un peso saludable";
  } else if (imc > 25) {
    indice = "Tienes sobrepeso";
  }
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = indice;
}
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener(onclick, printImc);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <form id="form">
    <label for="peso">Peso<input type="text" id="peso" class="data" placeholder="60 kg"></label>
    <label for="altura">Altura<input type="text" id="altura" class="data" placeholder="1.70 mts"></label>
    <button id="button">Ok</button>
  </form>
  <div id="indice">
    <h3>Tu índice de masa corporal es:</h3>
    <h2 id="h2">0</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="resultado">
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calculadoramasacorporal.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button submits the form, which as a result reloads the page (it's a quite irritating default if you ask me). You need to manually prevent this by adding `function printImc(event) { event.preventDefault();`

As pointed out by @NishantSingh, another solution is to define `type="button"` on the button to prevent reloading the page (I didn't know that).

Second error, `.addEventListener(onclick)` should be `.addEventListener("click")`.

Third error (more like a warning because it works nonetheless) : as pointed out by @jkoestinger, `.tofixed()` returns a string (!). `(altura * altura).toFixed(2)` is a string, and then you divide a number with a string, which shouldn't work... but still does, probably because JS automatically casts `"26.8"` to `26.8`.

```js
function printImc() {
  var peso = parseFloat(document.getElementById("peso").value);
  var altura = parseFloat(document.getElementById("altura").value);
  var imc = (peso / (altura * altura)).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("h2").innerHTML = imc;
  var indice = "";
  if (imc <= 18.5) {
    indice = "Tienes bajo peso";
  } else if (imc > 18.6 && imc <= 24.9) {
    indice = "Tienes un peso saludable";
  } else {
    indice = "Tienes sobrepeso";
  }
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = indice;
}
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", printImc);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <form id="form">
    <label for="peso">Peso<input type="text" id="peso" class="data" placeholder="60 kg"></label>
    <label for="altura">Altura<input type="text" id="altura" class="data" placeholder="1.70 mts"></label>
    <button id="button" type="button">Ok</button>
  </form>
  <div id="indice">
    <h3>Tu índice de masa corporal es:</h3>
    <h2 id="h2">0</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="resultado">
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calculadoramasacorporal.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would add as well that `toFixed` is to be used carefully here (even if it seems to work), as it outputs a string. So the line `peso / (altura * altura).toFixed(2)` is actually dividing a float by a string

Comment: `form` used here so the button will trigger form submit by default, it's better to define button type to "button".  `Event.preventDefault` is not required in this case.

Comment: @jkoestinger,  var imc = (peso / (altura * altura)).toFixed(2); was intention, i guess? Or, better toFixed(1), because of the message(indice).

Comment: I would like to know why my comment thanking all the above contributors for their useful comments, which helped me update my answer, was seemingly censored my a moderator... ???

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix it would be to change the form to a div (maybe a good idea as I think forms are more for submitting information to an api etc..)

Also I changed the .innrerHtml to .innerText as you only want to pass text to the element rather than more html elements

```js
function printImc() {
  var peso = document.getElementById('peso').value
  var altura = document.getElementById('altura').value
  var imc = (peso / (altura * altura)).toFixed(2)
  console.log(imc)
  var indice = ""
  if (imc <= 18.5) {
    indice = "Tienes bajo peso"
  } else if (imc > 18.6 && imc <= 24.9) {
    indice = "Tienes un peso saludable"
  } else if (imc > 25) {
    indice = "Tienes sobrepeso"
  }
  document.getElementById('h2').innerText = imc
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerText = indice
}
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', printImc)
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="form">
    <label for="peso">Peso<input type="text" id="peso" class="data" placeholder="60 kg"></label>
    <label for="altura">Altura<input type="text" id="altura" class="data" placeholder="1.70 mts"></label>
    <button id="button">Ok</button>
  </div>
  <div id="indice">
    <h3>Tu índice de masa corporal es:</h3>
    <h2 id="h2">0</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="resultado">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is your solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calculadora de masa corporal</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <form id="form">
            <label for="peso">Peso<input type="text" id="peso" class="data" placeholder="60 kg"></label>
            <label for="altura">Altura<input type="text" id="altura" class="data" placeholder="1.70 mts"></label>
            <button id="button" type="button">Ok</button>
        </form>
    <div id="indice">
        <h3>Tu índice de masa corporal es:</h3>
        <h2 id="h2">0</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="resultado">
    </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function printImc(){
    console.log("hello")
    var peso = parseFloat(document.getElementById("peso").value);
    var altura = parseFloat(document.getElementById("altura").value);
    var imc = peso / (altura * altura).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("h2").innerHTML = imc;
    var indice = "";
    if (imc <= 18.5){
        indice = "Tienes bajo peso";
    } else if (imc > 18.6 && imc <= 24.9) {
        indice = "Tienes un peso saludable";
    } else if (imc > 25) {
        indice = "Tienes sobrepeso";
    }
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = indice;
}
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", printImc);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Your code is good, a few mistakes are there like incorrect event listener, as well as the button type, is missing.

Comment: Many many thanks, now it works... didnt know button type could be button, great tip!